# Double to Hex String and Back

Tags: java, string, data-structures, hex

It's fairly simple to convert a double to a hexadecimal string in Java. But how do I do the reverse? My code is below and I've noted where a `NumberFormatException` is thrown (about 2/3rds down).

```
public class HexToDoubleTest {
    public static void main( String args[] ) {

        // This is the starting double value
        double doubleInput = -9.156013e-002;

        // Convert the starting value to the equivalent value in a long
        long doubleAsLong = Double.doubleToRawLongBits( doubleInput );

        // Convert the long to a String
        String doubleAsString = Long.toHexString( doubleAsLong );

        // Print the String
        System.out.println( doubleAsString );

        // Attempt to parse the string back as a long
        // !!! This fails with a NumberFormatException !!!
        long doubleAsLongReverse = Long.parseLong( doubleAsString, 16 );

        // Convert the long back into the original double
        double doubleOutput = Double.longBitsToDouble( doubleAsLongReverse );

        // Confirm that the values match
        assert( doubleInput == doubleOutput );

    }
}
```

Using `Double.valueOf` fails in the same manner.

Edit: I've done a few searches on the web already and found some very inelegant solutions. For example: Using a `BigInteger` seems like overkill. There's got to be a better way!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break the String into two halves and parse each one, but I think this is the simplest.

```
long doubleAsLongReverse = new BigInteger(doubleAsString, 16).longValue();
```

In Java 8, there is now a

```
long l = Long.parseUnsignedLong(doubleAsString, 16);
```

and to reverse this

```
String s = Long.toUnsignedString(l, 16);
```

These can be used in combination with the methods converting raw `double` to `long` etc.

Comment: Ended up doing this (even though I said I wanted to avoid BigInteger).

Comment: I tend to avoid BigDecimal/BigInteger as well, but sometimes its the best option.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - Is it possible to convert this long value back to the original string?

Answer (score 9):

Why not use the methods provided in standard library: 
[Double.valueOf](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) and [Double.toHexString](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toHexString%28double%29)

So a full round trip example would be

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    double doubleValue = -0.03454568;
    System.out.println("Initial double value is " + doubleValue);

    String hexStringRepresentation = Double.toHexString(doubleValue);
    System.out.println("Hex value is " + hexStringRepresentation);

    double roundtrippedDoubleValue = Double.valueOf(hexStringRepresentation);
    System.out.println("Round tripped double value is " + roundtrippedDoubleValue);
}
```

Nb `Double.valueOf` will give a boxed `Double` and `Double.parseDouble` will give a primitive `double` [choose as appropriate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10577630/2187042).

or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: This fails in the same exact manner: `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: @Andy: just to make sure, could you specify: a) the output of `String str = Double.toHexString(-9.156013e-002)` and b) `Double d = Double.valueOf(str)`

Comment: This seems to work for me, for very small numbers, very large number, negative and positive numbers. I think @Andy may not be reading exactly what you mean so I've made an edit to add examples of usage

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the input value is negative, and the javadoc for [Long.toHexString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#toHexString(long)) states "Returns a string representation of the long argument as an unsigned integer in base 16. The unsigned long value is the argument plus 2^64 if the argument is negative; otherwise, it is equal to the argument." However parseLong states "Parses the string argument as a signed long in the radix..."

So when you have a negative input, that 2^64 causes the NumberFormatException.

If the input is changed to

```
double doubleInput = 9.156013e-002;
```

the conversion works correctly without an exception. To deal with a negative input, a little additional processing is needed.

Here is a class that shows one way to do the conversion without using BigInteger or byte buffers:

```
public class Temp {
  public String getDoubleAsHexString(double input) {
    // Convert the starting value to the equivalent value in a long
    long doubleAsLong = Double.doubleToRawLongBits(input);
    // and then convert the long to a hex string
    return Long.toHexString(doubleAsLong);
  }

  public double convertHexStrToDouble(String input) {
    // convert the input to positive, as needed
    String s2 = preprocess(input);
    boolean negative = true;
    // if the original equals the new string, then it is not negative
    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase(s2))
      negative = false;

    // convert the hex string to long
    long doubleAsLongReverse = Long.parseLong(s2, 16);

    // Convert the long back into the original double
    double doubleOutput = Double.longBitsToDouble(doubleAsLongReverse);

    // return as a negative value, as needed
    if (negative)
      return -doubleOutput;

    return doubleOutput;
  }

  private String preprocess(String doubleAsHexString) {
    // get the first char and convert it to an int
    String s0 = doubleAsHexString.substring(0, 1);
    int int1 = Integer.parseInt(s0, 16);

    // if the int is < 8, then the string is not negative
    // and is returned without further processing
    if (int1 < 8)
      return doubleAsHexString;

    // otherwise subtract 8
    int1 = int1 - 8;
    s0 = Integer.toString(int1);

    // don't prepend a "0"
    if (int1 == 0)
      s0 = "";

    // return the string with a new inital char
    return s0 + doubleAsHexString.substring(1);
  }
}
```

And here is a junit test class:

```
public class TempTest {
  private Temp t;

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    t = new Temp();
  }

  @Test
  public void testConvertHexStrToNegativeDouble() {
      double doubleInput = -9.156013e-002;
      String hexStr = t.getDoubleAsHexString(doubleInput);
      double doubleOutput = t.convertHexStrToDouble(hexStr);
      assertEquals(doubleInput, doubleOutput, 0.0);
    }

  @Test
  public void testConvertHexStrToPositiveDouble() {
    double doubleInput = 9.156013e-002;
    String hexStr = t.getDoubleAsHexString(doubleInput);
    double doubleOutput = t.convertHexStrToDouble(hexStr);
    assertEquals(doubleInput, doubleOutput, 0.0);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Example function to reverse double value:

```
public Double ReverseDouble( Double d) {

   byte[] bytes = new byte[8]; 
   ByteBuffer.wrap( bytes).putDouble( d); 

   for (int i=0;i<bytes.length/2;i++) {
       byte b = bytes[ i];
       bytes[ i] = bytes[ bytes.length -i -1];
       bytes[ bytes.length -i -1] = b;
   }

   return ByteBuffer.wrap( bytes).getDouble();
}
```

Comment: This answer is not related to the question. But it rises an interesting point: Maybe NIO buffers can help?

Answer (score 0):

Conversion of HexString to Long.

```
public long ConvertHexToLong(String hexValue){
        return  new BigInteger(hexValue, 16).longValue();
     }
```