# How to make NumberFormat returns in double-type

Tags: java, string, double, number-formatting

The function below works perfectly, but I would like to make it to **return the value in double format**, as the function below return the value in String format.

```
private static String convertMoneyToSap(double val) {
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.GERMAN);
    nf.setGroupingUsed(false);
    return nf.format(val); //--> I would like this to return in double format
}
```

How can I do that? Thanks.

---

**UPDATE**

When I tried to use: `return Double.parseDouble(nf.format(val))`, I get error:

```
An error occurred: java.lang.NumberFormatException
```

The usage example of the function above is like:

```
convertMoneyToSap(1234567.89); //--> The expected result: 1234567,89
```

The expected result on the function above is returns as String. While I tried to use `Double.parseDouble()`, it will get an error message.

---

**UPDATE 2**

```
Double.parseDouble("1234,99") //--> will return error
Double.parseDouble("1234.56") //--> will return successful
```

The problem is, `nf.format(val)` will return something like: `1234,99` and it will return error while it comes to `return Double.parseDouble(nf.format(val))`.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5769679/1091781

Comment: what is the sense of converting from double to Double? they are basically the same

Comment: What does "double format" mean? What should the result look like (for given input)?

Comment: @IlyaBursov: Yes, they are. But I would like to change the locale so it would returns something like: `123.456,78` rather than `123,456.78`

Comment: So you want to convert double to string, this is what your current code do

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/703396/how-to-nicely-format-floating-types-to-string?rq=1

Comment: Yes, the code above is returning the value to String. But I would like  it to returns the value in double.

Comment: @mrjimoy_05 I believe the *textual representation of a double in a particular locale* is being confused with the *value* of a double. A double *value* does not have a "format".

Comment: what are you passing as val?

Comment: @metsburg: `1,234,567.89`, and I expect this to returns `1.234.567,89`

Comment: Unless I'm much mistaken, calling convertMoneyToSap(1,234,567.89) for the method given in the question will result in a compile time error. what am I missing here?

Comment: @metsburg: Yes, you are right. The method given will result error..

Comment: ok, so why are you passing three arguments to a method that takes one? what is you objective here?

Comment: @metsburg: I got what you mean. It should be me mistaken the method. But how can I allow the method to takes more than one arguments?

Comment: 1,234,567.89 is three arguments, 1 and 234 and 567.89, you can not use currency delimiters in the code. pass it as : 1234567.89

Comment: @metsburg: I still get an error, please see the update question above.

Comment: Check the update to my answer.

Comment: Accept the answer which you found useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
   Double.parseDouble();
```

only if you want to convert a value represented through a string to its corresponding double value.

The response to your question will depend on what nf.format(val) returns.

++++++++++++++++++

If you want the method to return the value of double or Double, the ',' delimiter to express the decimal point (based on localisation) cannot be used. double will represent 123.54 as 123.54 only, and not as 123,54.

If you want to use the localised format, make it a string. Else, split the value before and after the decimal point into two different double variables and represent them in whatever format suits you best (i.e, you handle the localisation work yourself).

Double.parseDouble() will not work on a localised or specially formatted string.

Comment: So you give me a `double` and .. I have to do all that work to get a `Double`? (And I'm not even sure it will work correctly across all locales!) Why not `Double.valueOf(val)` if that is the end goal?

Comment: Check this to know more about the difference between valueOf and parseDouble:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577610/what-is-difference-between-double-parsedoublestring-and-double-valueofstring

Comment: I don't see how that matters. If for some *odd* reason, one wanted a Double-that-did-not-reference-equal-any-other-Double it could be done with `new Double(val)`.

Comment: This is seriously insane what you're doing out there ! You don't use valueOf or parseDouble to convert double into Double. Do you know the difference between double and Double ?

Comment: the question said "return the value in double format", hence the reply. Agreed... it is useless. I didn't check the method first. It seems like user wants to convert 123,456.78 to 123.456,78. My response to the same is hence not valid.

Comment: @metsburg: Yes, you got what I mean. But unfortunately, while I tried to use `Double.parseDouble();`, it returns error. Please see the update above.

Comment: yes, understandable. what are you passing as 'val' ?

Comment: @metsburg: Thanks a lot!! It help me to solve the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Change return type to double, and change return statement to:

```
Double.parseDouble(nf.format(val));
```

Comment: Thanks, but it returns error, please see the update above.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Double.parseDouble()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29)

Replace with

> return Double.parseDouble(nf.format(val));

and make return type of the method as Double.

**Update answer**

include `val=val.replaceAll(",", "\\.");` before return statement.

Comment: Thanks, but it returns error, please see the update above.