# Java "" converted to Double

Tags: java

I want to know that will happen if I convert this:

```
   String ret = "";
```

to double:

```
   Double.parseDouble(ret);
```

When I run the problem I have a error saying Invalid double: ""

Comment: If you wanted to figure it out yourself, why ask it here?

Comment: What stops you from finding out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is difference between Double.parseDouble(string) and Double.valueOf(string)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577610/what-is-difference-between-double-parsedoublestring-and-double-valueofstring)

Comment: There's no problem to solve here. Closing to vote for being and off-topic question.

Comment: @GaneshThiagarajan I don't think it's a duplicate. That post at least has a valid question, while this one doesn't.

Comment: What I wanted to say is: My project is more complex than this. I just need to know the "return" to try something, instead of "hey, solve me this for me".

Comment: I edited now. I just wrote the part that everyone didnt understood right because it didn't let me ask without a amount of characters

Comment: Your giving the program a blank space and you expect it to return a double?

Comment: just tel us what exactly you are expecting as a return

Comment: I think OP just didn't clearly typed what he is looking for, so it doesn't mean that it should be discarded so brutally. Just my opinion.

Comment: @hagrawal if a question is very unclear, closing is the right thing to do. It's not immediately discarded. The question can still be edited and reopened. In this case, I think it's still very unclear, because it seems to say that he has already seen what happens. If he's seen what happens, his real question must not be "what happens?", because he's seen that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See below Java's implementation of `Double.parseDouble`

```
public static double parseDouble(String s) throws NumberFormatException {
    return FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(s).doubleValue();
}
```

Now check below code `FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString` [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java#FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString%28java.lang.String%29)

```
   in = in.trim(); // don't fool around with white space. throws NullPointerException if null
        int l = in.length();
        if ( l == 0 ) throw new NumberFormatException("empty String");
```

**To answer your question:**  Since you are passing empty string, you will get `NumberFormatException`.

Exception you will get as below. Notice the message (*"empty String"*) is same as what is can be seen in my second code snippet.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
```

Comment: Did you get your answer? If not then please write your own answer so that others can be benefited from it .. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 1):

It'll throw an exception `java.lang.NumberFormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

If you try to run the code

```
String ret = "";
double a = Double.parseDouble();
```

The compiler will throw a `java.lang.NumberFormatException`, meaning, in plain terms, you gave the program a type of input that could not be converted to a double. If you want to fix this then just give the program a parse able string (i.e 6, or 3.24). You could also use `try` and `catch` to throw different error messages if the wrong input is given.

Example:

```
public class Testing {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try{

            String ret = "";
            double a = Double.parseDouble(ret);

        }catch(NumberFormatException e){

            System.out.println("Your error message here");
            //do something (your code here if the error is thrown)

        }
    }
}
```

This would print out `Your error message here`, because the input "" can't be converted to a double.

More on NumberFormatException: [Click here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html).

More on parsing strings to doubles: [Click here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/Convertstringtodouble.htm).

More on try and catch: [Click here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html).

Comment: Thanks. My program return "" when I read a file. That file is inside the device internal storage. Does it return "" because of the double values that I am saving inside it?