# Parse String to Double with null values

Tags: java, string, double

I have to convert Strings to Doubles, but may be I have a null value. Does it work with `Double.parseDouble(stringValue)` or `Double.valueOf(stringValue)`?

What is the difference between this two methods?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're asking two different questions here. One of them is a duplicate of [What is the difference between Double.parseDouble(String) and Double.valueOf(String)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577610/what-is-the-difference-between-double-parsedoublestring-and-double-valueofstr). Please restrict yourself to one question per question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither method makes any difference. Both will throw a `NullPointerExecption`. Instead, you need to add a helper method which returns a `Double` e.g.

```java
static Double parseDouble(String s) {
    return s == null ? null : Double.parseDouble(s);
}
```

or you can return a `double` by having a default value

```java
static double parseDouble(String s, double otherwise) {
    return s == null ? otherwise : Double.parseDouble(s);
}
```

a suitable value might be `Double.NaN`

```java
static double parseDouble(String s) {
    return s == null ? Double.NaN : Double.parseDouble(s);
}
```