# Is Java's string representation of a double exact?

Tags: java

In other words, is the equality:

```java
Double.parseDouble(Double.toString(x)) == x
```

guaranteed by Java?

(Edited to use `parseDouble` to avoid unnecessary boxing.)

Comment: If it's exactly as you put it here then yea as valueof uses the cached value. Else you should use parseDouble: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10577610/what-is-the-difference-between-double-parsedoublestring-and-double-valueofstr

Comment: @scrappedcola: Why would caching make any difference?  If the result of `toString` were assigned to a `String` variable, and *that* was passed to `valueOf`, should the result be the same?

Comment: Comparing double values is always a very difficult topic, thus I would not depend on any `==` comparison on double values no matter how the value has been built/calculated.

Comment: `Double x` or `double x`? It isn't a good idea to mix the two with `==`

Comment: Degenerate example for a "No" answer: `NaN`.

Comment: I suspect the answer is no, even for values which are not NaN, since [the documentation of toString(double)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)) explicitly states that rounding is possible.

Comment: The results of parsing text into a `double` may vary across versions of Java, as floating-point semantics [changed](https://openjdk.org/jeps/306).

Comment: I believe the answer is intended to be yes with the exception of degenerate values such as NaN, and that the rounding mentioned in the Javadoc is only intended to indicate that the result of toString may not always be the shortest decimal that parseDouble would convert back to the original value.

Comment: It can’t be exact. Base-2 and base-10 fractions are incommensurable.

Comment: @Robert: My need is to transfer doubles across the network as part of a text-based protocol.

Comment: @user207421: Do you have an example where the equality is not true (besides NaN that's not even equal to itself)?

Comment: @teapot418 I've just tried and it works both for `"NaN"` and `"Infinity"`. It's also consistent with the JavaDoc.

Comment: @AlexeyVeleshko for `double x` and `NaN` OP's expression should return false because nan is not equal to itself (hence 'degenerate').

Comment: @teapot418 Oooh... indeed! I didn't bother to actually compare the results.

Comment: The question in your title and the question in your question do not agree, and the ‘in other words’ inference does not follow. I was commenting on the question in your title.

Comment: @user207421 The question is: Does the string exactly represent the double? This is consistent with the Java equality (except for the pathological case of NaN). I never said anything about real numbers, which you seem to have in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is. If you look at the [documentation of `toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#toString(double)), after describing the edge cases of special values, there is written

> *Selection of a decimal*: A well-defined decimal d<sub>m</sub> is selected to represent m **[absolute value of the `toString` argument]**. This decimal is (almost always) the shortest one that rounds to m according to the round to nearest rounding policy of IEEE 754 floating-point arithmetic.
>
> *Formatting as a string*: The decimal d<sub>m</sub> is formatted as a string, either in plain or in computerized scientific notation, depending on its value.

In other words, the conversion will not give the *exact* representation of the binary floating-point number in its decimal form. It will, however, provide sufficient number of digits for the result to round back to the input (using round-to-nearest rounding of the IEEE 754 standard). The `toString` implementation will also try to choose the shortest possible form that satisfies this condition.

See also the [documentation of `valueOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) method (which is a synonym for `parseDouble`). Here you can confirm the correspondence between various special cases and that round-to-nearest is used for the reverse conversion.

**EDIT**: More [reading](https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8202555).

**EDIT2**: As noticed by @teapot418, the case of `NaN` technically breaks the equality. This is, however, because of how `NaN` comparison is defined by the standard. If your `x` is `NaN`, `Double.parseDouble(Double.toString(x))` will still be `NaN`.

Comment: I'm fairly convinced (especially from the text in JDK-8202555). I still wish the specification state it more directly.